# Perl hash referencing

Tags: c#, perl, hash, reference

If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it. Currently I am working on converting some old Perl scripts to C# but in doing so I keep coming across code in the following syntax:

`$w{$x}->{y} = $z`

I understand the basics of hash in Perl but I'm fairly new to Perl in general and I cannot find an example like this anywhere.

Is this just saving a reference to a value of a key in a hash?

Comment: It should be pointed out that the arrow between `{$x}` and `{y}` is completely unnecessary.  It doesn't hurt anything, except (IMO) readability.  If you leave it out, suddenly the expression looks much more like a 2-dimensional structure with which you may be more familiar, and it's easier to see that `%h` is, in effect, a hash of hashes. `$w{$x}{y} = $z`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Paul, I agree with you in regards to readability lol. This had me tripped up for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working backwards, it is assigning the value of `$z` to the key `y` of a hash reference, where that reference is assigned to key `$x` of a hash named `%w`.

```
perl -wMstrict -MData::Dumper -E 'my %h; my $x=1;  $h{$x}->{y}=3; print  Dumper \%h;'

$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'y' => 3
                 }
        };
```

In Perl, the values of list-type data structures can only be scalar items (single entities), so everything under the first level of a hash must be a reference. A reference is simply a scalar value that holds a 'pointer' to the item in question.

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have an hash `%w` which contains a key `$x`. The value behind the key `$x` is a reference to another hash. So you deference it with the `->` to access the key `y`. The value of the key `y` is set to the value of `$z`.

So it looks like:

```
%w = ($x => {'y' => $z})
```

Note: The `{}` indicate a hash-reference. (basically a pointer to a hash).